# Run method on session expire Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm using session to store an object id and its description, this instance should be blocked to all other users while it is beign used in someone's session, and I would like to release the user object once he closes the browser, now I'm aware there is a configuration to expire sessions on browser close, I was just wandering if there is any entry point where I could add some custom code

What I'm trying to achieve is something like

```
def OnSessionExpire(???):
     #release my objects
```

I've searched around but found no answer, can someone lay a help here? I'm using the backend session mode

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't do anything at all when the browser closes. Django doesn't even know - how can it: the only time Django knows anything about what you do in the browser is when you make a request to the server, but closing the browser is the opposite of making a request.

Session expiry on browser close is an attribute of the session cookie, not anything that Django does. It just means that the cookie is set with a flag that tells the browser not to persist it when it closes. The actual session data remains in Django's session store, and will do until you explicitly clear it, but is not accessible because the cookie has been removed.

So, the upshot of that is that there is no way to tell explicitly when a session ends. The only thing you can do is to send regular keepalive signals - eg via Ajax - while the session is open, and taken an action if you haven't seen any for a while.